# Specific Permutations in R

Tags: r, permutation

I am trying to create permutations of the alphabet `{0,1,2,3}` using `combinat::permn`.

The thing is that I want each one of the permutations to be converted to the form of `'%s-%s-%s'`..etc and to be stored in a list. For example,

```
> library(combinat)
> permn(numbers[1:4])
[[1]]
[1] "0" "1" "2" "3"
[[2]]
[1] "0" "1" "3" "2"
 .
 .
 . and so on
```

But I want to convert the output for all permutations into a list of string sequences of my specific format, i.e. `'0-1-2-3', '0-1-3-2` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lapply` to apply `paste` on each of the vectors and collapse them with the delimiter you want (in this case "-").

```
lapply(permn(0:3), paste, collapse = "-")
```

If you just want the output as a vector instead of a list you could use `sapply` in place of `lapply`

Comment: No need for `lapply`. Simply pass `paste, collapse = "-"` to the `FUN` parameter in `perm` like so: `combinat::permn(0:3, paste, collapse="-")`